# How to re-enable Ctrl + C to copy HTML elements in Chrome developer console?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I currently have the version 58 of Google Chrome. I noticed since some time that it is no longer possible to make a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy the HTML elements from the chrome developer console.

We still can copy, but we are obliged to do `right click > Copy> Copy element`. This is really inconvenient at all.

[image]

How can I use **keyboard shortcuts** in the console again to copy HTML elements, like before ?

Comment: https://crbug.com/722534

Comment: It's fixed in Chrome canary 60 which you can install separately to use until Stable channel upgrades to v.60.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your answer. Will wait for the release